# Is "how is this a syllabus" correct?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

Is "how is this a syllabus" correct? Can I use the article "a" in that question?

The situation is following: I've asked my son's history teacher to provide his teaching plan for this year. He sent to me a paper describing his teaching methods instead. Perhaps, it's a mistake. So I am writing a letter to him and asking him a simple question: "How is this a syllabus? It looks more like description of your teaching style instead."

So, is "a" in there okay?

Comment: Yes, that has exactly the meaning you want; but be aware that this is a confontational way of expressing it (which may be what you intend). The implication is something like "there is no way that this can possibly be a syllabus", and suggests unspoken things like "you must be an idiot to send it".

Comment: I agree with Colin!  The grammar is fine, but if you do not intend to be a little bit rude - or express that you are maybe slightly angry - say something like "Is the this syllabus?  I expected a description of the curriculum, but this looks more like **a** description of your teaching style."  If you wanted to soften it further, you could say "**Apologies**, but is actually the syllabus...."  It does not indicate you are actually apologizing for any particular thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement sounds rude and confrontational to be honest. You could think of pursuing a more considerate approach as follows:

> My apologies, but this doesn't look like a syllabus. This is more like your teaching methods in the class. Do you mind sending the correct document again?

However, if you are willing to stick to your approach, I must say, there is no mistake. The article must be present to indicate the *sent* document is not the correct one you are looking for.

Comment: It's more common to say "confrontational"

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA Adjective, not the verb form. I definitely get confused sometimes.